# Is $ d(X) \le s(X)? $

Tags: general-topology

Is the density of X always less than or equal to the spread of X? If not, can someone help me find a counter example?

$s(X) = sup ( \vert A \vert : A \textrm { is a discrete subset of } X ) $

$d(X) = \min ({ \vert D\vert : \overline{D} = X})$

Answer (score 3):

No, though for Hausdorff spaces we have $d(X)\le 2^{s(X)}$, and for linearly ordered spaces with the order topology we have $d(X)\le s(X)^+$.

Let $X=\Bbb R$, let $\tau_e$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, and let

$$\tau=\{U\setminus C:U\in\tau_e\text{ and }C\subseteq X\text{ is countable}\}\;;$$

$\tau$ is a topology on $X$, and henceforth when I refer to $X$, I’ll be talking about $\langle X,\tau\rangle$.

Clearly no countable subset of $X$ is dense, so $d(X)>\omega$. Let $A$ be an uncountable subset of $X$. It’s well-known that there is a $p\in A$ such that every Euclidean nbhd of $p$ contains uncountably many points of $A$. But then every $\tau$-nbhd of $p$ contains uncountably many points of $A$, so $A$ is not discrete, and $s(X)=\omega$.